# Copy rows which have specific character and paste them in a new file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a file which looks like this:

```
Cx  100 350

C   110 320

Cn  300 250

Cb  200 280

Cx  300 210
```

I want some how with bash scripting to select specific rows which contain character "Cx" and "Cn" and paste them in a new file.

Comment: `grep 'C[xn]' file > newfile`

Comment: Keep it simple: `grep -e "Cx" -e "Cn" file > newfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep`:

```
grep '^C[nx]' file >newfile
```

This would pick out the lines that *start* with the string `Cn` or `Cx` and save those lines to a new file called `newfile`.

This would still pick out line that start with e.g. `Cxx` or `Cn!`.

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "Cn" || $1 == "Cx"' file >newfile
```

This would do a string comparison instead of a regular expression match.  It would let through only those lines whose first whitespace-delimited column was exactly `Cn` or `Cx` and nothing else.

Comment: Or grep '^C[xn]\>'

Comment: @ctac_ I had that in there until I realized that my example `Cn!` would still be outputted.  I guess it would be better with `^C[nx][[:blank:]]`. It's safer to use `awk` and a plain string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=any -lane '
   print if any { $F[0] eq $_ } qw/Cx Cn/;
' input.txt
```

The module List::MoreUtils is loaded to access the any routine , which picks the first truth statement from a multitude of values. The solution given is extensible, if you want to add/modify the first fields to check for.

In the event that the above module could not be found, then the below code can be used:

```
perl -lane 'for my $e ( qw/Cx Cn/ ) { print,last if $F[0] eq $e }' input.txt
```